# insertar datos en formulario custom wordpress, ajax, php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, formularios

hola estoy creando un formulario en un template de wordpress pero al ejecutar no me guarda los datos, el formulario es simple php, hice una seccion con html puro, al cual le agrego la ruta del archivo js que en este caso es app.js, y en la función submit lo envio a un archivo php que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto, ademas le incluyo el archivo de conexion a la base de datos ( es una base de datos externa, pero alojada en el mismo servidor local, phpmyadmin). el tema es que me llega la información al archivo js, puedo mostrar los datos por consola, al enviarlos del archivo js al php en la consola me aparece que llega me manda un status 200, pero no me guarda la información, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!-- El formulario -->

    <div class="row" style=" margin: auto; width: 90%; border: 3px solid green; padding: 10px;">

    <div class="contact-form col-sm-6 wow slideInUp">
    <div class="wpforms-container wpforms-container-full">

    <form id="pedido-form" name="pedido-form" method="post" action="" class=" wpforms-form customize-unpreviewable"  >
    <div class="wpforms-field-container">

    <div id="delynombrediv" class="wpforms-field">
    <label class="wpforms-field-label">Nombre
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="delynombre" class="wpforms-field-medium " name="delynombre" required="">
    </div>

    <div id="delyapellidodiv" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-name" >
    <label class="wpforms-field-label">Apellido
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="delyapellido" class="wpforms-field-medium " name="delyapellido" required="">
    </div>

    
    <div id="delytelefonodiv" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-name">
    <label class="wpforms-field-label">Telefono
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="delytelefono" class="wpforms-field-medium " name="delytelefono" required="">
    </div>

    
    <div id="delydirecciondiv" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-name">
    <label class="wpforms-field-label">Direccion
    <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="delydireccion" class="wpforms-field-medium " name="delydireccion" required="">
    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="wpforms-submit-container">
    <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>
    </div>

    </form>


    </div>  <!-- .wpforms-container --></div>
           
     <div class="col-sm-6 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: slideInUp;">
      <h4>pedido.</h4>
      <p>algojhasgdj asjdhajhsd asdjhas <br>
      fjsdfjskdfsdfsdf</p>
      <br><br>
      <div class="address-box">
       <div class="address-contact">
       <span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
        <div class="address-content">Despacho a domicilio</div>
        </div>
        <div class="address-contact">
         <span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>
         <div class="address-content">+569 48631669</div>
        </div>
       </div>
     
    </div>
    </div> 

    <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Frontend Logic -->
       <script src="http://localhost/www/app.js"></script>
   </div>
```

El archivo js:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#pedido-form').submit(function(e){
        const postData = {
            nombre: $('#delynombre').val(),
            apellido: $('#delyapellido').val(),
            telefono: $('#delytelefono').val(),
            direccion: $('#delydireccion').val()
        };
        console.log(postData.nombre);
        $.ajax({
            data:  {postData}, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   'http://localhost/www/pedido-add.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'POST', //método de envio
            success: function (response) {
                if(!response.error) {
                console.log(response);
                }
              } 
    });
 });

});
```

El archivo php:

```html
<?php

include('database.php');

    if (isset($_POST['delynombre'])) {
        $nombre = $_POST['delynombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['delyapellido'];
        $telefono = $_POST['delytelefono'];
        $direccion = $_POST['delydireccion'];
        $id_tipo_usuario = $_POST[2];

            $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre_usuario,apellido_usuario,telefono_usuario,direccion_usuario,id_tipo_usuario) VALUES 
            ('$nombre','$apellido','$telefono','$direccion','$id_tipo_usuario')";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            if (!$result) {
                die('fallo la consulta');
            }
            echo "usuario agregado";
            
    }
```

el archivo de conexion a la base de datos:

```html
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect(
        'localhost',
        'root',
        '',
        'deli'
    );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí están los archivos, los tengo en la ruta, intento conectarme a otra base de datos, en el mismo servidor, alguna opinion de que estoy haciendo mal? gracias de ante mano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo hacerlo con hooks y te ahorras la conexion a la base de datos. Ahora... Nunca pasa del IF porque $_POST['delynombre']  no existe, pero si existe $_POST['nombre']. Esto esta definido en tu variable postData y creo que ponerlo entre llaves está de más. Avisame si hay avances :D

Comment: Te doy el ejemplo para apache, cuando usas wordpress el .htaccess redirige todos los request al wordpress por lo que cuando pones algo aparte para que funcione independiente, normalmente no funciona. La forma de agregar un formulario es detro del framework. Podes hacerlo con un plugin tipo ninja forms o programarlo, pero tenes que usar hooks y templates para eso. Es mucho lo que habria que explicar. Lo mejor es que busques un tut y veasl wordpress codex para entender lo que vas haciendo.

Comment: @BryanRetamal gracias, era error de tipografía, ciego jaja